# Listbox width changes regardless of size of list items

Tags: wpf, listbox, width, actualwidth

**Please see Update at bottom of post**

I'm writing a WPF app using .Net 4.5

I have a `ListBox` displaying movie info, the xaml is shown below.

```
<ListBox Margin="10, 5, 10, 10"
             ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResponse.Results}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                             Handler="SearchResult_OnMouseDoubleClick">
                </EventSetter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#3e3e42"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Background="#242424"
                        Padding="10">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailPath}"
                               Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                                Path=DataContext.ThumbnailWidth}"
                               Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                                Path=DataContext.ThumbnailHeight}"
                               Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                        <StackPanel TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe WP"
                                    TextBlock.FontSize="14"
                                    TextBlock.Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
                                    Width="300">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Every thumbnail (Image) in the list will have the same width and height (either small, medium or large).
For the window I have `SizeToContent=Width` so the window will resize itself when the thumbnail size is changed.

The problem is this:
When I scroll the `ListBox` using the mouse wheel the `ListBox` width changes seemingly randomly and causes the window to increase in width.
If I scroll using the scroll bar up and down buttons this doesn't happen.

I've debugged the `ActualWidth` of all of the elements in the `ListBox` item data template (text blocks, stack panels, border, etc.) and they all stay at the expected fixed width yet debugging the width of the listbox itself shows that it changes width randomly.

Here are two screenshots. The first shows the correct layout and the second shows the layout after scrolling the `ListBox` with the mouse wheel.

[image: Correct layout]

[image: After scrolling, listbox gets wider!]

So, why does the `ListBox` `ActualWidth` change when the items contained within do not?

**Update:**
Some further investigation suggests that this behaviour is being caused by the fact that the images I am using for the thumbnail are larger than the thumbnail display size and are resized by the image control. It appears that the listbox is (sometimes) resized according to the original image size rather than the smaller resized image.

Anyone have any suggestions to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by writing a `MultiValueConverter` which takes in an image filepath and a pixel width (bound in xaml using a MultiBinding) and returns the correct size bitmap to display in the thumbnail Image control. The result is that the correct size image is used (and cached) so the `ListBox` width is constant.

This is the code for the converter:

```
public class PathToThumbnailConverter : IMultiValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var path = values[0] as string;
        var decodeWidth = (int)values[1];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            var info = new FileInfo(path);

            if (info.Exists && info.Length > 0)
            {
                var bi = new BitmapImage();

                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.DecodePixelWidth = decodeWidth;
                bi.CacheOption=BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.UriSource=new Uri(info.FullName);
                bi.EndInit();

                return bi;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is the xaml for declaring it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <valueConverters:PathToThumbnailConverter x:Key="ThumbConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And using it:

```
<Image.Source>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ThumbConverter}">
    <Binding Path="ThumbnailPath"/>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="DataContext.ThumbnailWidth"/>
   </MultiBinding>
</Image.Source>
```